# Determining what relation means

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, multisets

If we have to consider the relation R from {1,2,3,4} to {3,4,6,7,9} given by aRb ↔ b = a + 3 then would the relation given be {1,2,3,4,6,7,9}? I'm a little confused on what is meant when I'm being told to consider a relation R from one relation to another.

Comment: You’re not being told to consider a relation from one relation to another: you’re being told to consider a relation from the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ to the set $\{3,4,6,7,9\}$. The relation $R$ cannot possibly be $\{1,2,3,4,6,7,9\}$: $R$ is by definition a subset of $\{1,2,3,4\}\times\{3,4,6,7,9\}$, so it is a set of ordered pairs. One member of $R$ is the pair $\langle 1,4\rangle$, because $4=1+3$; another is $\langle 3,6\rangle$, because $6=3+3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relation on sets $A$ and $B$, $a R b$, $a \in A, b \in B$ is a subset of $A \times B.$ If $a R b,$ then $(a,b) \in R.$ So if $b=a+3,$ then $(a,b) \in R.$

$$R= \{ (1,4), (3,6), (4,7)\}.$$